# How can we "persuade" fink, port, & brew to coexist in parallel on OSX Mavericks?

Tags: macos, gnome, macports, homebrew, fink

We like to use `brew`, but it doesn't have a lot of `gnome` toolset *formulae*, and we can install a `gnome-terminal` very quickly with `FinkCommander`.  We've built various parts of `gnome` from scratch, but creating a `brew` formula just to get the `gnome-terminal` seems overkill, when it is already available.

Regardless, we were having trouble building `gnome-terminal` with `FinkCommander`, that is until we removed all `brew` installed component references from environment variables; we certainly had to take `/usr/local/bin` and `/usr/local/opt/gnu-tar/libexec/gnubin` out of `$PATH`, and just for kicks, we made sure `${DY}LD_LIBRARY_PATH` didn't point into `/usr/local/lib`, etc.   This allowed `gnome-terminal` to build & install successfully with `FinkCommander`.

Further, we have software which we want to install via `brew`, `fink`, **and** `port` - but `brew` does not *play well with others*.  This has led to the more general question:  Is it enough just to toggle *path* and *environment variables* to *switch between* `brew` and `fink`/`port` *build environments* and *installations*?  We know we need to *hide* `brew` from `fink` via environment variables when building `gnome-terminal` with `FinkCommander`, and the assumption is that for some `brew` defined formula, the reverse is true.

What in general must we do to have the best of all three worlds?  That is, what to do to have all three, `brew`, `fink`, and `port`, built and installed in parallel?  Because all the managed *packages* were built from scratch, each *package* should know where their own dynamically linked libraries are located.  Is it enough to jumble around the `$PATH`, `$MANPATH`, & `$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variables *on the fly* to put one installation *in front of* another to use its defined tools?  Are we missing anything?

Comment: A thought would be to create 3 small VM's whose purpose in life is to build `brew`, `fink`, & `port` "releases" which are exported and mounted, or even rsync'd, into the proper location on the host.  Therefore, the builds will build against libraries extent on the host but will not interfere with each other when built and only the necessary bin, lib, man, etc. paths will be exported to their appropriate locations on the host.

Comment: rsyncing and mounting via brew's paradigm wouldn't work too well because of brews extent level of indirection it already employs i.e. the tools are sym linked into /usr/local/bin, so we cannot simply copy the installation into place, but we'd need to manage links to the built tools.

Comment: I have never had a problem with this though. Fink, MacPorts, and Brew are ALL installed on my computer, and they all play nicely. Brew triggers a *warning* when it finds the others, but it still operates just fine.

Comment: Yeah, I've got all installed at the same time, now, and I wonder about the `brew doctor` warnings.  The only thing that I've found that can be problematic is that the gnu tools don't seem to handle ACL (`gtar` for instance), which is a feature and not a build configuration issue - of course, if some other tool depended on that features' existence...

Comment: It is not impossible for `tar` to handle  ACLs. For an implementation that handles ACLs (explained [here](http://cdrtools.sourceforge.net/private/star-acl.html) and extended attributes well, take a look at `star`, a very mature (1982) `tar` implementation that is still actively maintained by its original author. You can either compile it using one of the aforementioned ports systems, or install as part of [schilytools](http://schilytools.sourceforge.net).

Answer (score 3):

Let me answer that from the MacPorts perspective I come from, as these problems of co-existing software management tools are not unknown there. Most importantly, there simply is no way to remove `/usr/local` from the default compiler search paths. This may lead to problems with some builds, especially during a multi-architecture `+universal` compilation.

In the beginning of the project many years ago, MacPorts switched to `/opt/local` in order to avoid problems with other software. Total isolation from `/usr/local` does not seem to be possible at all by compiler configuration flags alone. Unfortunately, Homebrew developers deliberately ignored this and chose /usr/local as their default. While it sounds like a good idea as it would be already listed in PATH, in the default configuration `/usr/local/bin` only occurs after `/usr/bin`, making it impossible to overwrite any command line tools. So there is no advantage of using `/usr/local` at all.

Best solution is to either install Homebrew to any other path (for example `/opt/homebrew`), or to rename /usr/local temporarily before building and rename it back afterwards:

```
sudo mv /usr/local /usr/local.off
... # do your compilation work
sudo mv /usr/local.off /usr/local
```

As a side note for the future, while MacPorts in its current version is already using a sandbox for all builds, there are improvements in this area coming for version 2.3.0 or later. The new trace mode currently in development would allow to limit all file access to those files required for the particular build task only, hiding locations like `/usr/local` and `/sw` completely from the build process. However, that won't help with other tools unless they adopt this feature as well.

Answer (score 1):

Since each port system usually comes with different quirks (and the occasional port failing to build due to some weirdness hidden deep down its path of dependencies), I've got one system with HomeBrew, MacPorts and FreePorts installed in parallel. 
For the build environment, it's usually sufficient to keep them from detecting the other port system installations during build and compile time to keep them separated so they don't start weaving dependencies upon each other, or worse fail and bail due to a dependency detected in the wrong port tree.

So far, it has been enough to initialize a clean building environment that only has the system directories (make sure to avoid `/usr/local` for MacPorts, Fink, FreePorts, see [Raims answer](https://superuser.com/a/717287/115318)) + its own target directories in its search paths, linker path, etc the way already described in the Question above.

For building, I preprend the port systems tree in the order of directories searched, to avoid getting configure-time complaints about outdated versions detected in the stock MacOSX by the port build system. For the user running the port, it's safer to append those trees, to give preferrence to the OS-supplied binaries.

If you need to copy the installed port trees, [`ditto`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/ditto.1.html) would be the tool of choice. From the manpage:

> `ditto` will preserve resource forks and HFS meta-data information when copying unless instructed otherwise
>        using `--norsrc` .  Similarly, `ditto` will preserve extended attributes and Access Control Lists
>        (ACLs) unless `--noextattr` or `--noacl` is passed.

Another option would be `/usr/bin/rsync -avSEH`:

- `a`rchive mode,
- `v`erbose is optional,
- `E` to preserve extended attributes and ACLs,
- `S` to handle sparse files correctly (without expanding them to their full capacity, taking more space than the original), and
- `H` to preserve hard links.

For a `tar` that handles ACLs (explained [here](http://cdrtools.sourceforge.net/private/star-acl.html)) and extended attributes well, take a look at `star`, a very mature (1982) `tar` implementation that is still actively maintained by its original author. You can either compile it using one of the aforementioned ports systems, or install as part of [`schilytools`](http://schilytools.sourceforge.net).